# Make CSS dropdown content align to the right instead of the left

Tags: html, css

The content of this dropdown (the box) is aligned left under the icon.  I need it aligned under it to the right.  Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-span {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="dropdown">
  <span><i class="far fa-caret-square-down fa-lg"></i></span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah!  Sorry.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may helpful. 
By adding **right:0;** in .dropdown-content

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-span {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="dropdown">
  <span><i class="far fa-caret-square-down fa-lg"></i></span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so simple!  Thanks! Will mark as answer when it lets me in 7 minutes :)

Comment: My Pleasure.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add **right: 0** property to dropdown-content class.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Sorry - I can tell from the other answer that I misunderstood your question. I'll leave this reply here for posterity.

Here's a hack that hard codes the height of the dropdown icon as 18px.

The difference between your original code and mine below is:

- `top: 18px;` added to `.dropdown-content` css rule
- `display: inline-block` updated in `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content` css rule

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-span {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 18px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="dropdown">
  <span><i class="far fa-caret-square-down fa-lg"></i></span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```